# vertical-align:middle for a span element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the text in a span to align vertically in the middle relative to adjacent text. This is easily achieved, however when the text in the span takes up two lines, the text is cut-off. 
To solve this problem the span either needs to expand in height when the text takes up two lines, or to somehow align the text to the middle..

A working example of the problem is here http://jsfiddle.net/BxLnN/

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

The current dimensions of the containing elements must remain the same.

Cheers!

the html

```
<div class="divisions_container">
    <div class="division">
        <div class="div_head">
            DIVISION 1 <span>SIX WINNING NUMBERS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="div_head">
            DIVISION 2
            <div>
                <span>FIVE WINNING NUMBERS PLUS ONE OF THE TWO SUPPLEMENTARY NUMBERS</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css

```
/* division winnings */
.divisions_container {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 7.4cm;
    height: 8.5cm;
}
.div_head {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    max-height: 6mm;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    }
/* # winning numbers */
.div_head span {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the `span` with `position: absolute;`. When you make an element absolutely positioned, it becomes a `block` element without any margins, and you cannot use `vertical-align` on them, as it works only on `inline` and `inline-block` elements.

So I suggest this CSS:

```
/* division winnings */
.divisions_container {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 7.4cm;
    height: 8.7cm;
}
.div_head {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    max-height: 6mm;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    }
/* # winning numbers */
.div_head span {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;

}

.div_head div {position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/BxLnN/1/

Comment: I tried adding a containing div for the span myself, but for whatever reason I couldn't get it to work so gave up on it. Thanks for figuring it out :)

Comment: as an aside, setting the .div_head to have a top padding of 2px seems to produce a more consistent effect rather than using top:-2px for .div_head div.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible for you to set a fixed height to your span, like `20px` or so, then you could use: `line-height: 20px` in your `.div_head span` style. That would then center the text in your `span` automatically.

You also don't need to set a `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` that way.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BxLnN/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this works...
You must specify width of span and position to relative and increase or decrease the value of top and left;

```
.div_head span {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work but having the span stretch out like that is less than desirable. Some weird behavior when changing the width too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this works...
You must specify width of span and position to relative and increase or decrease the value of top and left;

```
.div_head span {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**The Nice One Is Here**
*HTML*

```
<div class="Division_Container">
<span>Division 1</span>
<span class="Inner_Container">
six winning numbers
</span>
</div>
<div class="Division_Container">
<span>Division 2</span>
<span class="Inner_Container">
five winning numbers and rest of the nubmers to be displayede winning numbers and rest of the nubmers to be displayed
</span>
</div>
<div class="Division_Container">
<span>Division 2</span>
<span class="Inner_Container">
five winning numbers and rest of the nubmers to be displayede winning n
</span>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.Division_Container{display: block; width: 300px; background: #000; color: #fff; margin: 10px;}
.Inner_Container{display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; left: 200px;  width: 200px; margin-left: 20px; border: 1px solid red;}
/* If you want to specify height add following */
.Division_Container:before{content: "."; display: inline-block; height: 100px; vertical-align: middle; visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: See this [Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/96/) and [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/97/)